# 7zip: How to extract multiple zip files with output folder the same as input?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, 7-zip

So I have like multiple zip files (50 of them) i.e "alaska.zip", "canada.zip", "foo.zip", "houston.zip" and I want the output folder the same as input name i.e "alaska" folder for "alaska.zip" . In windows I can use "extract to" option, but since in ubuntu 7z dont have gui so no "extract to" option in right click.  How do I do that?

I tried this, instead it said "no files to process"

7z x {wildcard}.zip -o{wildcard}

Note:
{wildcard} = *

Comment: The "Extract to..." menu on right-click is provided by file archiver GUI (such as `file-roller`), and not by 7zip (`p7zip`) in Ubuntu/Linux.

Answer (score 2):

Use a loop:

```
for file in ./*.zip  
do 
    7z x "$file" -o"${file%.zip}"
done
```

Comment: shell script? no built in command in 7z?

Comment: @Jul yeah, but you don't really need to write a script. You can type/paste it directly on the command line